# How to download 6Gb - 500Gb files using python within lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

On an hourly basis I have to download files ranging from 6-10Gb and on a daily basis I have to download a file that ranges from 25-45Gb and monthly the file ranges from 400-500Gb.  Currently this is all being done using perl and it works great but now we are moving to AWS and Lambda and with Lambda's 15 minute max process time my code times out.  If I happen to have a files that is less than 5.5Gb the lambda python function I have written works just fine.  So my hope is that someone has had to tackle this sort of problem and can help me out.  Here is a stripped down version of the function as it sits right now.

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import dateutil.tz
import urllib3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
    s3object = boto3.resource('s3')

    bucketName = "test-bucket"
    checkDir = "check"

    fileURL = 'https://export.dnsdb.info/dnsdb-export/mtbl/dns.20200930.0700.H.mtbl'
    # Check to see if the file exists in S3 bucket
    fileExists = True
    
    try:
        s3.head_object(Bucket=bucketName, Key=checkDir + '/' + file)
    except ClientError as e:
        fileExists = False

    # If the file doesn't exist, download it
    if not fileExists:
        http = urllib3.PoolManager()
        hdr={'X-API-Key' : 'api-key'}
        response = http.request('GET', fileURL, preload_content=False, headers=hdr)
        s3.upload_fileobj(response, bucketName, checkDir + '/' + file)
        response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucketName, Key=checkDir + '/' + file)
```

Comment: Does it have to be with Lambda? Would EC2 maybe be more appropriate for this?

Comment: Looks more like a job for AWS Batch

Comment: Why does the comment say "download it", yet the code says `upload_fileobj()`? How are you downloading such big files given that Lambda has a limit of 512MB of `/tmp/` disk space? This use-case does not appear to be suited to using AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda can only be used for 15 minutes per execution. This means if your download takes longer than that, you will get a timeout like you describe. Essentially you're limited by your download speed, but getting a 500 GB file in under 15 minutes means downloading with >560 MB/s which is unrealistic in most scenarios. Perhaps consider using an EC2 instead of Lambda.

Comment: I know all about the 15 minute limitation.  Currently it is running on an EC2 instance so if we have to leave the monthly one there that is fine.  I was hoping someone would have used multi threading to split the hourly and daily files up so that I could at least save the parts to an s3 bucket so I could put them back together in another function.

Comment: @TerryJensen doing the multithreaded split thing would be possible but it's not something people here are going to do the legwork on for you if you haven't shown what you've tried or researched.

Comment: If it is working on EC2, then use that! You can save money by turning off the instance when not in use. See: [Auto-Stop EC2 instances when they finish a task - DEV Community](https://dev.to/aws/auto-stop-ec2-instances-when-they-finish-a-task-2f0i)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas:

- you can put the file somewhere "closer", e.g. on the same region. This could give you a crazy download speed ([https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-maximum-transfer-speed-ec2/#:~:text=Traffic%20between%20Amazon%20EC2%20and,and%20the%20bucket%20are%20in.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-maximum-transfer-speed-ec2/#:%7E:text=Traffic%20between%20Amazon%20EC2%20and,and%20the%20bucket%20are%20in.))
- you can increase the memory of your lambda. This increases the CPU the AWS gives to your lambda, which may reduce the download time even further (https://theburningmonk.com/2020/03/how-to-optimize-lambda-memory-size-during-ci-cd-pipeline/)